# angularjs and textarea: how to get change without ng-model

Tags: angularjs, inject

I have a form with a textarea element:

```
<textarea ><?php echo $user->field_descrizione[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']; ?></textarea>
Chars left: {{charsLeft}}
```

As you can see the textarea value is get from a php variable (Drupal notation, in this case) and not with an angular ng-model, so I can not use ng-change, ng-maxlenght and other angular things.

There is a possibility to inject my php'value in a angular $scope variable at runtime?

something like :

```
<script>
    $scope.textareavalue = <?php echo $user->field_descrizione[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']; ?>
</script>
<textarea ng-model='textareavalue'></textarea>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but maybe you could use `ng-init`.

Something like

```
<textarea 
ng-init="textareavalue = '<?php echo $user->field_descrizione[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["safe_value"]; ?>'"
ng-bind="textareavalue">
</textarea>
```

Comment: It does not work:-- Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 106-106 [è] in expression [textareavalue = io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ? io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ? io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ? io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ? io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ? io sono la descrizione. Ma se c'è la signature ho senso ?].--

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the placement of ''. I updated my answer, you might try `ng-init="textareavalue = '<?php echo $user->field_descrizione[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["safe_value"]; ?>'"`. How does the textarea-element look in the inspector in your browser? Does php properly inject the value?